# How To Add The Same Shader/Material To Multiple Objects?

Tags: materials, shaders, workflow

I want to apply or use the same material for multiple objects. How can I do this without doing it per object ? The target objects already have their own materials and I don't want to override them. I just want to add new material slot  and same material across multiple objects.

I can't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to link material because it will replace existing material.

Any solution ?

---

The real case is, I'm building a house (3 floors) with basic furnitures. So I got many walls, floors, windows, doors, kitchen set , fence etc.

All these objects has their own basic material setup :

- wall : concrete, white paint
- door : wood panel, inox, black frame
- window : glass, inox ,black frame, alluminium
- etc.

There is a unique wall (wall A) has a material i want to copy.

- wall A : concrete, white paint, **SECTION**

So I want to use this **section** material into all other objects on the scene (those other walls, doors, windows, kitchen set etc). There are many objects so I'm looking a way to apply this **section** material without manually applying per object. And I want to keep the existing material :

- wall : concrete, white paint, **SECTION**
- door : wood panel, inox, black frame, **SECTION**
- window : glass, inox ,black frame, aluminum, **SECTION**

I can't find a way to apply selected material to multiple objects without replacing the existing material.

Thanks

Comment: To clarify:  You have many objects with many materials and you want to add a second material slot to these objects so that they all still have their own first materials and share a second material in their second slot?

Comment: @Allen : yes, the target objecs already have 1 or more material. So i want to add second/third slot with this new material. (not replacing the existing slots).

Comment: Can you add more details? I mean if some function can add these materials, how about link them to the object faces? So why just add?

Comment: @lemon i've edited my post , adding some more details on it. Pls have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Python is needed again here.

Answer (score 2):

```
import bpy


# Input material's name to append
matname = "SECTION" 

if matname in bpy.data.materials :
    mat = bpy.data.materials[matname]
    objs= bpy.context.selected_objects
    for obj in objs :
        if obj.type == "MESH" :
            if matname not in obj.data.materials :
                obj.data.materials.append(mat)
else :
    print("Material '" + matname+ "' does not exist")
```

Comment: matvalid = matname in bpy.data.materials, matexist = matname in obj.data.materials

Comment: @scurest , thanks a lot !